# Failed "make menuconfig"

Tags: kernel, make, ncurses

Until now I was able to run `make menuconfig` successfully. I tried to install cmake packages and thereafter I get,

`make menuconfig`:

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/dullollis/esp/esp-idf/tools/kconfig'
lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh -check /usr/bin/gcc  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -I/mingw32/include -I/mingw32/include/ncursesw -DCURSES_LOC="<ncurses.h>" -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 -DLOCALE -MD -L/mingw32/lib -lncursesw -lgnurx -ltre -lintl -liconv -lpsapi -lintl
 *** Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the
 *** required header files.
 *** 'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.
 ***
 *** Install ncurses (ncurses-devel) and try again.
 ***
make[1]: *** [Makefile:203: dochecklxdialog] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/dullollis/esp/esp-idf/tools/kconfig'
make: *** No rule to make target '/home/dullollis/esp/esp-idf/tools/kconfig/conf', needed by '/home/dullollis/esp/CAN/build/include/config/auto.conf'.  Stop.
```

Although I have the ncurses (ncurses-devel) libraries up to date.

What am I missing?

Comment: Having only the error message to go by, it looks like the ncurses library is missing.

Comment: Well, a bit too little info here. We know little about the host and the target (distro, architecture) and it's also not clear if the `ncurses-devel` package (?) contains the `ncursesw` library (`.a` and/or `.so`) or whether that's a separate package.

Answer (score 1):

This line shows a problem:

```
lxdialog/check-lxdialog.sh -check /usr/bin/gcc  -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=199506L -I/mingw32/include -I/mingw32/include/ncursesw -DCURSES_LOC="<ncurses.h>" -DNCURSES_WIDECHAR=1 -DLOCALE -MD -L/mingw32/lib -lncursesw -lgnurx -ltre -lintl -liconv -lpsapi -lintl
```

which looks as if the user's environment has set **`CC`** or **`CFLAGS`** to cross-compile for ***MinGW32***, and it's confusing **`check-lxdialog.sh`** (by finding libraries that it cannot link with).